# Turning a list number, into another value that is returned [python]

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am currently working on this code:

```
def N_C(question,choice):
    N_C_choice_count_max = len(choice)
    N_C_choice_count_min = N_C_choice_count_max - N_C_choice_count_max
    N_C_restart_input = True
    N_C_choices = []
    print(question)
    for i in range (N_C_choice_count_min,N_C_choice_count_max):
        print(N_C_choice_count_min+i+1,":",choice[i])
        str(N_C_choices.append(N_C_choice_count_min+i+1))
    while N_C_restart_input == True:
        N_C_input = input(">")
        if str(N_C_input) in str(N_C_choices):
            break
        else:
            continue
    return(N_C_input)

N_C("question",["choice1","choice2","asmanychoicesasyouwant"])
```

And it works fine as it is, but to select a choice you input the number of the choice, which makes sense, but I would like for it to instead return the number they choose, the actual choice that goes with that number.

I am thinking that maybe something with a dictionary could work, or even just using the choice list provided, but I cannot figure it out, and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*choice* is a list containing all the answers and *N_C_input* is a number as a string, which is associated to *choice*.

```
return choice[int(N_C_input)-1]
```

Returns the actual choice.

Comment: Thanks, It was quite simple after all, just wanted to finish this program and couldn't think of it.